# How to convert self-defined types, e.g. geometry, to and from String?

Tags: scala, gis, slick

There is geometry type column in database like Postgis or h2gis(I am using it).
In the console provided by database, I can create a geometry value with `select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.3 12)', 4326)`. 
Or select a column with geometry type simply by `select * from geom`.

However I don't know how to insert a geometry value (a string actually) into a table or the opposite direction conversion.
There are also several miscellaneous question below.

Here is the table definition in slick:

```
class TableSimple(tag:Tag) extends Table[ (Double,String,String) ](tag,"tb_simple"){

  def col_double = column[Double]("col_double",O.NotNull)
  def col_str = column[String]("col_str",O.NotNull)
  def geom = column[String]("geom",O.DBType("Geometry"))
  def * = (col_double,col_str,geom)
}
```

**1. About select**

The most simple one:

```
 sql" select col_double,col_str, geom from tb_simple ".as[(Double,String,String)]
```

won't work unless casting `geom` to `string` explicitly like:

```
 sql" select col_double,col_str, cast( geom as varchar) from tb_simple ".as[(Double,String,String)]
```

The first sql throws the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException`

**Q1: How does slick know `com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException` (it is lib used by h2gis)? Is it an error on the server side or client side(slick side)?**

**Q2: How to convert/treat column `geom` as string without writing too much code(e.g. create a new column type in slick)?**

**2. About insert**

First of all the following sql works

```
StaticQuery.updateNA("""  insert into tb_simple values(11,'abcd',ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5.300000 1.100000)', 4326))  """).execute
```

I hope code like `TableQuery[TableSimple] += (10.3,"hello","ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.300000 1.100000)'")` would work but it doesn't.
It shouldn't because slick translate it to

```
insert into tb_simple values(11,'abcd','ST_GeomFromText(''POINT(5.300000 1.100000)'', 4326)')
```

Notice the function `ST_GeomFromText` become a part of string, that's why it doesn't work.

**Q3: Can I implant a string directly for a column instead of wrapped with `''` in slick?**

I hope I can insert a row as easy as `TableQuery[TableSimple] += (10.3,"hello","ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.300000 1.100000)'")` or similar code.

**Q4** What's the most convenient way in Slick to implement bidirectional conversion to and from String for a geometry or other self-defined column in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Answering you main question: Slick-pg offers mapping of geometry types in the db to actual geometry types in your model.

It works for Postgis, but maybe it can also work with H2Gis.

You can find slick-pg at https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

Comment: Hi @Christophe, I know slick-pg though not try it yet. I am seeking a simple solution instead of a heavy wrapper. Besides I also want to know how to write code a customized column data type myself :D

Comment: We use slick-pg for some projects, I wouldn't call it a heavy wrapper. But slick-pg is a good way to learn how to write a customized column type if you can peak how it's done there :)

But for a quick outline: you'll have to make a custom DriverJdbcType subclass that maps your type. In slick-pg this is the GeometryJdbcType.

Comment: Initially I think `MappedColumnType` would solve the problem. So it is impossible to do Q3 in my question? I have to implement a new JDBCtype?